# Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" null pointer Exception NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a multi threaded application where i get some request from JMS, threads are running to receive the message. Here how my thread is working:

Model mapper in the try block is causing the issue i think:

```
patientAdder.addPatient(patientAddMessage, authResult, queueSender, baseUrl, modelMapper);
```

here is complete code:

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
  while (true) {
SonicQueueMessageSender queueSender = null;
                    try {
                        queueSender = new SonicQueueMessageSender(queueConnProvider);
                    } catch (JMSException e3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e3.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    String patientAddMessage = null;
                    try {
                        patientAddMessage = new SonicMessageReceiver(connectionProvider)
                                .getAddJsonMessage("MirthMessage");
                    } catch (JMSException e2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    final AuthModel auth = new AuthModel();
                    String authResult = null;
                    final PatientAdder patientAdder = new PatientAdder();
                    SecurityTokenModel securityToken = null;


                    String authPostString = null;
                    try {
                        authPostString = new ObjectMapper()
                                .writeValueAsString(auth);
                    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    System.out.println("Auth post string is: "+ authPostString);
                    System.out.println("base url is: " + baseUrl);
                    String authPostOutput = client
                            .doGetAuthRestPost(authPostString, url);
                    try {
                        securityToken = getAuth(authPostOutput);
                    } catch (JsonParseException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JsonMappingException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    authResult = securityToken.getAccessToken();
                    try {
                        patientAdder.addPatient(patientAddMessage, authResult, queueSender, baseUrl, modelMapper);
                    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // poster.postMessage(patientAddMessage, authResult);
                    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

}
}
});
```

I need to map the message i'm getting in request to a bean class and for that i'm creating a `ModelMapper` class object that has a function to map properties but when i try to create new object of my mapper class i'm getting a NPE:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.prnreferral.util.commons.ModelMapper.mapCanonicalMessageToPatientModel(ModelMapper.java:82)
    at com.prnreferral.patientprocess.add.PatientAdder.addPatient(PatientAdder.java:52)
    at com.prnreferral.patientprocess.add.PIXSAddPatient$1.run(PIXSAddPatient.java:148)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I'm sure that object is created as i checked it by adding some conditions, but there is something that i'm missing causing this issue
I also tried to add a new function to check if there is any issue with this function, but getting

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.prnreferral.util.commons.ModelMapper.printString()V
at com.prnreferral.patientprocess.add.PatientAdder.addPatient(PatientAdder.java:49)
at com.prnreferral.patientprocess.add.PIXSAddPatient$2.run(PIXSAddPatient.java:173)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I'm stuck on this issue, no idea what to do, can anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: more code snippet and stack trace will help in investigating issue

Comment: @Apollo done, can you check now, if you have any idea on this.

Comment: A `NoSuchMethodError` is usually the result of compiling against version B  of a dependency but running with version A. This can happen easily in networked applications where there's a library version mismatch between client and server.  Check to make sure that you're compiling against the same dependencies that your test gets run against.